# Prestashop Category Price

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-modules

I have a site where the categories show the prices in 0.00, but if add to the cart the price is right ( also de product price are correct). I leave you a URL of the problem.
https://brooks-espressomachines.com/en/13-faema-e61-espresso-machine

I will appreciate your help.

Regards